# About canonical momentum operator as generators of translation

Tags: quantum-field-theory

As we know, translations in Minkowski space form a group, it may be represented by a unitary operator, satisfying:

$$ U(a)U^\dagger(a) = 1 \tag{1}$$
$$ U(a)U(b) = U(a+b) \tag{2}$$
$$ U(0) = 1 \tag{3}$$

The U satisfying these is
$$ U(a) = e^{i a_\mu G^\mu} \tag{4}$$
where $G^\mu$'s are Hermitian operators(matrices), called the generators of the group.

In QFT, for a scalar field, we have
$$ U(a)^{-1}\phi(x)U(a) = \phi(x-a) \tag{5}$$
or
$$ [\phi(x), G^\mu] = i \partial^\mu \phi(x) \tag{6}$$

On the other hand, the canonical momentum operator is defined as
$$ P^\mu \equiv \int d^3 x T^{0\mu} = \int d^3 x \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_0\phi)}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_\mu} - g^{0\mu} \mathcal{L} \right) \tag{7}$$

In QFT textbooks, $ P^{\mu}$'s are taken as generators of $U(a)$,
$$ U(a) = e^{i a_\mu P^\mu} \tag{8}$$

but no rigorous proofs. For example, the validity of $P^\mu$ as the generators may depend on the particular Lagrangian from which $P^\mu$ is constructed.

So, under what conditions, $P^\mu$ may be taken as generators of a translation group?

Comment: From (6) you can see that the only possible solution for $G_\mu$ is $i\partial_\mu$ that is the definition of the momentum operator.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Conserved charges and generators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358266/84967).

Answer (score 1):

Well, one *normally* assumes your Lagrangian density has a standard kinetic term, so it is bilinear in the canonical momenta $\pi=\partial_0 \phi$ and the space gradients of $\phi$. The [canonical commutation relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization#Real_scalar_field), then,
$$
  \left[\phi\left(\vec{x}\right), \pi\left(\vec{y}\right)\right] = i \delta\left(\vec{x} - \vec{y}\right),
$$
in addition to the trivial ones, with vanishing right-hand side, yields 
$$
[\vec{P},\phi(\vec{x})]= -i\nabla \phi (\vec{x}), 
$$
so that the [Hadamard lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma) reduces to 
$$
e^{-i\vec{a}\cdot \vec{P}} \phi  e^{i\vec{a}\cdot \vec{P}} = e^{-i\operatorname {ad} \vec{a}\cdot \vec{P}  } \phi= e^{ -\operatorname {ad} \vec{a}\cdot \nabla   } \phi (\vec{x})= \phi (\vec{x}-\vec{a}),
$$
the standard [Lagrange translation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator).

Now extend this construction to a chiral nonlinear σ-model which is not just bilinear, as here. Do you see the proper commutation relations in terms of the chiral fields required?  [Hint](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/4/1/383/pdf).