# Noether charges of spacetime translation in KG field

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

When applying a spacetime translation $x^\mu\rightarrow x^\mu+a^\mu$ the KG lagrangian density changes by -

$$\mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathcal{L} + a^\nu \partial_\mu \delta^\mu_{\;\nu} \mathcal{L}$$ 
giving rise to the momentum-energy tensor and the corresponding conserved charges.

The first one is the energy -

$$Q^0 =\intop d^3x (\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot\phi}\dot\phi-\mathcal{L})=E$$ this is obvious since the integrand is simply the Legendre transform of the Lagrangian density.

But the the other charges, associated with the spatial momentum are less clear to me -
$$Q^i =\intop d^3x \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot\phi}\partial^i\phi=p^i$$
 What is the intuitive meaning of the integrand here? $\pi=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot\phi}$ is already the field's momentum density. And what is the meaning of the spatial derivative?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Conserved charges and generators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/358266/84967).

Comment: After correction of expressions 2 and 3 they would state the total energy and momentum.

Comment: @my2cts you are correct, but the first part of your comment is what I said and the last part is what I asked.

Comment: Where did you say that your formula's needed correction? Where did you say tvat the integrand if formula 3 is the momentum density?